# fixed points of holomorphic maps between hyperbolic surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

While studying Riemann surfaces I came across this question:
If $f$ :S $\rightarrow$ S is a holomorphic map between hyperbolic Riemann surfaces then $f$ at most one fixed point unless some iterate $f^{k}$ is the identity map.

Using Pick's theorem we know that if $f$ isn't a conformal automorphism or a covering map then it is strictly distance reducing and so for $f$ to have at least two fixed points it has to be either of the above two. But now I don't know how to proceed from here.

Some help with this would be highly appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Is $S$ assumed to be compact?

Comment: No , There isn't any assumption like that

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/592552/user10354138 can you please enlighten me on this problem?

Comment: *Hint*: Consider the set of directions of all minimising geodesics joining two fixed points.